# How to render HTML inside Slim templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I'm trying to render a link preceded by an icon. I'm using [Slim](https://github.com/stonean/slim) templating engine along with [Bootstrap CSS](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons).

Usually you could do this the following way:

```
<a href="#"><i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile</a>
```

According to Slim's documentation, we can use `==` to render without escaping HTML. So, translating this to Slim, I tried the following variations:

```
li== link_to "<i class='icon-user'></i> My Profile", current_user
li== link_to "#{'<i class="icon-user"></i>'.html_safe} My Profile", current_user
li= link_to "#{'<i class="icon-user"></i>'.html_safe} My Profile", current_user
```

All variations rendered `<a href="/users/1"><i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile</a>` escaping the `i` tag.

How can I stop Slim or Rails from escaping html?

(Rails 3.2 with Slim 1.2.1)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to disable HTML escaping for the `link_to` argument, not the entire `link_to` result. You're pretty close with your `html_safe` but your string interpolation is eating your "safe for HTML" flag. This should work better:

```
li= link_to '<i class="icon-user"></i> My Profile'.html_safe, current_user
```

Answer (score 15):

This has been answered, but if you actually have some html and you want to render it in a slim template, use double equal.

```
== "<i>test</i>"
```

Will be the same as

```
= "<i>test</i>".html_safe
```

Comment: Cool, I guess it won't work when we have a line having code too, instead of mere html.

Comment: @ARK I think it does https://github.com/slim-template/slim#output-without-html-escaping-

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, you could write this as

```
li
  a href=url_for(current_user)
    i.icon-user My Profile
```

which arguably is a little easier to read.

Comment: Adding that if you have an attribute value which should be rendered as safe html, use double "=": `span data-icon==icon` (where the last icon is a variable that contains &#...;)

Comment: @elado: doesn't the slim documentation tell the exact opposite: https://github.com/slim-template/slim#output-without-html-escaping- ?

Comment: `==` doesn't escape, `=` does. You can use `tag attr=variable` to render an escaped variable. if you don't wish to escape it, use `tag attr==variable`. For example, to render an html entity as an attribute correctly, you shouldn't escape it: ruby: `icon = "&#123;"` slim: `span.icon data-icon==icon`

Comment: I do not approve of the edit to my answer. The extra brackets and the pipe do add too much noise and yield little benefit imho. I chose my code on purpose. Can I undo the edit?

Answer (score 1):

There's another way of tackling this below in case it helps anyone. Using a block is especially useful if you have more complex code to include within the link.

```
li
  = link_to current_user do
    i.icon-user>
    | My Profile
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a similar technique using slim syntax instead of 'raw' html, if you prefer:

```
li = link_to Slim::Template.new{ "i.icon-user\n| My Profile" }.render.html_safe, current_user
```

renders to be:

[My Profile](/current_user_url)

or raw:

```
<li>
  <a href="/current_user_url">
    <i class="icon-user"></i>
    My Profile
  </a>
</li>
```

In the above example to render the 'My Profile' text as asked in the question, you will need to use `"` which allows the use of `\n` or new line to form the correct slim syntax. `\t` would give you the tab you need if doing nested slim.

If it is okay to render the text inside the icon element, then the following would work:

```
li = link_to Slim::Template.new{ 'i.icon-user My Profile' }.render.html_safe, current_user
```

[My Profile](/current_user_url)

```
<li>
  <a href="/current_user_url">
    <i class="icon-user">My Profile</i>
  </a>
</li>
```

if put the behavior in your own helper method:

```
# ApplicationController.rb

def string_to_slim(string)
  Slim::Template.new{ string }.render.html_safe
end
helper_method :string_to_slim # allows you to call the method in a view via ERB or Slim
```

Then you could implement like this in view `.slim` being rendered by controller inheriting from your base controller:

```
li = link_to string_to_slim('i.icon-user My Profile'), current_user
```