# Data disable with icon slim template

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Working on a Rails app using slim. I have a problem passing html to slim on a button using data-disable-with attribute.  I would like to show the icon on the button when someone clicks.

```
 = f.submit t("basket.next_step"), class: "btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-block", id: "submit_form", data: { disable_with: "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>..."}
```

I have tried .html_safe but no luck.  Please see similar questions but in .erb 
[How to set html on data-disable-with to rails submit_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549067/how-to-set-html-on-data-disable-with-to-rails-submit-tag)
and [How to render HTML inside Slim templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988163/how-to-render-html-inside-slim-templates) for options i have tried.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hrm, I am using Rails 4.2 and `.html_safe` works for me in this case.

Comment: @Benjamin, was your issue ever resolved?

Comment: @jeffdill2 you need to use f.button instead of f.submit

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin, that was actually the answer I submitted to you. ;-)  Glad it's working.

Comment: Ahh i didn't realise. I fixed this a year ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `f.submit` to `f.button`. The button tag handles markup differently than the submit tag.